# In DB2 for z/OS, can I rebuild multiple indexspaces with one command?

Tags: db2, db2-zos

On DB2 for z/OS version 10, an errant utility left MANY indexspaces in a status of "RW,RBDP" within a specific database. I can successfully use the REBUILD INDEXSPACE command to fix them one-by-one, but there are A LOT of them. So, I was hoping for some kind of wild-card or *ALL option, but that doesn't yet work for me.

Is there a way to do the equivalent of the following?

REBUILD INDEXSPACE (MYDB.*)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can most assuredly rebuild ALL indexspaces, but I was hoping to rebuild all of them within a specific database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do an entire database at a time, but you could do some queries along with a [LISTDEF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/ugref/src/tpc/db2z_utl_listdef.html) to get a similar result.

First, find the indexes in question:

```
SELECT '  INCLUDE INDEX ' || RTRIM(CREATOR) || '.' || RTRIM(NAME)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES
WHERE DBNAME = 'MYDB'
```

That will give you the list of indexes related to that database. Then, you can take the results as part of a larger LISTDEF. Here's some example JCL (honestly, I'm not sure how much of this is specific to my shop, so there may be some changes required):

```
//*****************************************************
//*  RUN REBUILD INDEX UTILITY                         
//*****************************************************
//IXRBREST EXEC PGM=IEFBR14 DUMMY STEP FOR RESTART     
//IXRBUTIL EXEC DB2UPROC,SYSTEM=DB2T,COND=(4,LT)       
//STEPLIB DD DSN=DB2.PROD.SDSNLOAD,DISP=SHR            
//DB2UPROC.SYSIN DD *                                  
LISTDEF INDEXES                                        
  <insert generated list here>

REBUILD INDEX LIST INDEXES                             
      SORTKEYS SORTDEVT SYSDA SHRLEVEL CHANGE          
      STATISTICS REPORT YES UPDATE ALL                 
      MAXRO 240 LONGLOG CONTINUE DELAY 900 TIMEOUT TERM
      DRAIN_WAIT 50 RETRY 6 RETRY_DELAY 30
```

That should get you the indexes that need to rebuild. If there are some that need to be rebuilt, and some that are fine, you could add `SCOPE PENDING` to the `REBUILD INDEX` utility, and it will only rebuild those in a pending state.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to REBUILD is to do a DROP/CREATE. This is necessary when the datasets are missing or damaged. Unless you specify DEFER on index create, you get a REBUILD for free. DB2 extracts the index from the tablespace VSAM Linear in all cases.

Comment: That is an excellent point, Burton. Thanks!